# The deletion of span in the content editable in mobile does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are spans in the content editable div which needs to be deleted all at once. Now this works fine on the chrome desktop but when I try to delete it on the following devices this does not works.I am testing it on following

> 1. Chrome on Android
> 2. Safari on Mac, iOS
> 3. Firefox on Windows

When I try to delete the box looses focus and span does not delete.

This is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/aw8x5Lza/) to what I have tried so far.

```js
var EditableDiv = document.getElementById('EditableDiv');

       EditableDiv.onkeydown = function(event) {
         var ignoreKey;
         var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
         if (!window.getSelection) return;
         var selection = window.getSelection();
         var focusNode = selection.focusNode,
           anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;

         var anchorOffset = selection.anchorOffset;

         if (!anchorNode) return

         if (anchorNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != '#text') {
           if (anchorOffset < anchorNode.childNodes.length)
             anchorNode = anchorNode.childNodes[anchorOffset]
           else {
             while (!anchorNode.nextSibling) anchorNode = anchorNode.parentNode // this might step out of EditableDiv to "justincase" comment node
             anchorNode = anchorNode.nextSibling
           }
           anchorOffset = 0
         }

         function backseek() {

           while ((anchorOffset == 0) && (anchorNode != EditableDiv)) {

             if (anchorNode.previousSibling) {
               if (anchorNode.previousSibling.nodeName.toLowerCase() == '#text') {
                 if (anchorNode.previousSibling.nodeValue.length == 0)
                   anchorNode.parentNode.removeChild(anchorNode.previousSibling)
                 else {
                   anchorNode = anchorNode.previousSibling
                   anchorOffset = anchorNode.nodeValue.length
                 }
               } else if ((anchorNode.previousSibling.offsetWidth == 0) && (anchorNode.previousSibling.offsetHeight == 0))
                 anchorNode.parentNode.removeChild(anchorNode.previousSibling)

               else {
                 anchorNode = anchorNode.previousSibling

                 while ((anchorNode.lastChild) && (anchorNode.nodeName.toUpperCase() != 'SPAN')) {

                   if ((anchorNode.lastChild.offsetWidth == 0) && (anchorNode.lastChild.offsetHeight == 0))
                     anchorNode.removeChild(anchorNode.lastChild)

                   else if (anchorNode.lastChild.nodeName.toLowerCase() != '#text')
                     anchorNode = anchorNode.lastChild

                   else if (anchorNode.lastChild.nodeValue.length == 0)
                     anchorNode.removeChild(anchorNode.lastChild)

                   else {
                     anchorNode = anchorNode.lastChild
                     anchorOffset = anchorNode.nodeValue.length
                       //break       //don't need to break, textnode has no children
                   }
                 }
                 break
               }
             } else
               while (((anchorNode = anchorNode.parentNode) != EditableDiv) && !anchorNode.previousSibling) {}
           }
         }

         if (key == 8) { //backspace
           if (!selection.isCollapsed) {

             try {
               document.createElement("select").size = -1
             } catch (e) { //kludge for IE when 2+ SPANs are back-to-back adjacent

               if (anchorNode.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN') {
                 backseek()
                 if (anchorNode.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN') {
                   var k = document.createTextNode(" ") // doesn't work here between two spans.  IE makes TWO EMPTY textnodes instead !
                   anchorNode.parentNode.insertBefore(k, anchorNode) // this works
                   anchorNode.parentNode.insertBefore(anchorNode, k) // simulate "insertAfter"
                 }
               }
             }


           } else {
             backseek()

             if (anchorNode == EditableDiv)
               ignoreKey = true

             else if (anchorNode.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN') {
               SelectText(event, anchorNode)
               ignoreKey = true
             } else if ((anchorNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == '#text') && (anchorOffset <= 1)) {

               var prev, anchorNodeSave = anchorNode,
                 anchorOffsetSave = anchorOffset
               anchorOffset = 0
               backseek()
               if (anchorNode.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN') prev = anchorNode
               anchorNode = anchorNodeSave
               anchorOffset = anchorOffsetSave

               if (prev) {
                 if (anchorOffset == 0)
                   SelectEvent(prev)

                 else {
                   var r = document.createRange()
                   selection.removeAllRanges()

                   if (anchorNode.nodeValue.length > 1) {
                     r.setStart(anchorNode, 0)
                     selection.addRange(r)
                     anchorNode.deleteData(0, 1) 
                   } 
                   else {
                     for (var i = 0, p = prev.parentNode; true; i++)
                       if (p.childNodes[i] == prev) break
                     r.setStart(p, ++i)
                     selection.addRange(r)
                     anchorNode.parentNode.removeChild(anchorNode)
                   }
                 }
                 ignoreKey = true
               }
             }
           }
         }
         if (ignoreKey) {
           var evt = event || window.event;
           if (evt.stopPropagation) evt.stopPropagation();
           evt.preventDefault();
           return false;
         }
       }

       function SelectText(event, element) {
         var range, selection;
         EditableDiv.focus();
         if (window.getSelection) {
           selection = window.getSelection();
           range = document.createRange();
           range.selectNode(element)
           selection.removeAllRanges();
           selection.addRange(range);
         } else {
           range = document.body.createTextRange();
           range.moveToElementText(element);
           range.select();
         }
         var evt = (event) ? event : window.event;
         if (evt.stopPropagation) evt.stopPropagation();
         if (evt.cancelBubble != null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
         return false;
       }
```

```css
#EditableDiv {
          height: 75px;
          width: 500px;
          font-family: Consolas;
          font-size: 10pt;
          font-weight: normal;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
          background-color: white;
          overflow-y: scroll;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        #EditableDiv span {
          color: brown;
          font-family: Verdana;
          font-size: 8.5pt;
          min-width: 10px;
          /*_width: 10px;*/
          /* what is this? */
        }
        #EditableDiv p,
        #EditableDiv br {
          display: inline;
        }
```

```html
<div id="EditableDiv" contenteditable="true">
&nbsp;(<span contenteditable='false' onclick='SelectText(event, this);' unselectable='on'>Field1</span> < 500)  <span contenteditable='false' onclick='SelectText(event, this);' unselectable='on'>OR</span> (<span contenteditable='false' onclick='SelectText(event, this);' unselectable='on'>Field2</span> > 100 <span contenteditable='false' onclick='SelectText(event, this);' unselectable='on'>AND</span> (<span contenteditable='false' onclick='SelectText(event, this);' unselectable='on'>Field3</span> <= 200) )
</div>
```

I am using javascript for this. 
I am developing a solution for a app using meteor and blaze UI for templates which will run on iOS.

Comment: Hey Have you got any breakthrough?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the css `cursor:pointer;` on the div that you want to click on and delete.

Sometimes mobile browser, esp. Safari doesnt allow click event on the element unless it has cursor:pointer. It will trigger that this div is link or clickable.

Comment: But will this delete the span by backspace?

Comment: It does not works `cursor:pointer;` I have updated the fiddle . Please check

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Any solution? Meanwhile I'm gonna have to put some long press event on the span and offer option to delete it within the nodes of editable div. But direct backspace deletion would be better.